# How do you fix" FileName.exe has triggered a breakpoint" in VS?

Tags: c++, vector

I am making a piece of code that takes the vefctor "nums" and sorts it into odd and even numbers and then outputs two vectors, one with all even numbers and one with all odd numbers. However, whenever I run my program I get FileName.exe has triggered a breakpoint. Does anyone know the solution? any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
int main() {

std::vector<int> nums = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(nums); i++) {
        if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::vector<int> evennums = {};
            evennums.push_back(nums[i]);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << evennums[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::vector<int> oddnums = {};
            oddnums.push_back(nums[i]);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << oddnums[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program has a bug. Because you are running it from the Visual Studio IDE it breaks into the debugger at the exact moment the bug is triggered. You can use this to inspect the state of your program and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You allow it to stop in the debugger then set the "Stack Frame" to your code to see the line of your code that was executing when this happened.

Comment: `evennums` and `oddnums` are kind of pointless because you will only have 1 item in them. However your bug is in all places you are using the wrong value as the number of items in the vector. `sizeof(nums)` is not the number of items in the `nums` vector. `10` is not the number of items in `evennums` or `oddnums` they will both be fixed at 1. To get the number of elements you need to use  `vector::size()`. In the case of `nums` its `nums.size()`. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size)

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to obtain the size of the vector `nums` invokes undefined-behavior. The `sizeof(nums)` will return the size of that vector in bytes. Fortunately, there is a built-in member function for vectors for this work: `nums.size()`.

Also, you're accessing an out-of-bounds index of the vector `evennums` and `oddnums` – they contain a single element in your code. You're keeping redefining the vectors in every iteration of the outer loop that discards the previous one.

The correct code is as follows (notice comments):

```cpp
// To display the elements contained in the vector container
void display(const vector<int> p) {
  // This is called a range-based loop
  for (const auto& it : p)
    cout << it << ' ';

  cout << endl << endl;
}

int main(void) {
  const vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

  // Defining these vectors outside to prevent discarding its data
  // inside the loop that happened in your code
  vector<int> oddNums;
  vector<int> evenNums;

  for (const auto& it : nums)
    // Making condition, if true, it's even, otherwise, odd
    if (it % 2 == 0)
      evenNums.push_back(it);
    else
      oddNums.push_back(it);

  // Calling the subroutine defined above to display on the screen
  display(oddNums);
  display(evenNums);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that I've used range-based loops for ease of reading and to make the program look simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(nums); i++)
```

... doesn't do what you think it does. It [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) the size of `vector` in bytes, not the number of elements in it.

Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
```

Or better, a [range-based](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for loop:

```
for (auto element : nums)
```

Also,

```
std::vector<int> evennums = {};
evennums.push_back(nums[i]);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << evennums[i] << endl;
}
```

You're creating a vector and pushing only 1 element in it. If your loop iterates more than once, any `evennums[i]` access will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: (Not my vote) The beginner-friendly way to loop through a vector is just `for (int num : nums)`. Can get an array bound wrong that way.

Comment: @MSalters Indeed. I just thought introducing the `size()` method would suit what OP wants to do, instead of their misconception about `sizeof`. I added it to my answer, thanks for pointing it out.